# What is the fastest (lowest latency) messaging queue solution for sending a message from host A to host B?

Tags: real-time, messaging, rabbitmq, message-queue, zeromq

Ok folks, NOT counting ethernet speed (Infinitband), kernel bypass or any other fancy stuff, just plain TCP/IP (TCP/UDP over Ethernet) networking. What is the fastest messaging queue implementation that can deliver a message from host A to host B?

Let's assume 10Gigabits ethernet cards connecting both machines with up-to-date architecture and CPUs. What latency in microseconds are we talking here for a 1472 bytes message (MTU - IP/UDP headers)?

---

As @Sachin described very well, what I am looking for is the **messaging queue and the latency number** to send a message from A to B like below:

Host A <-------TCP-------> Messaging queue (process, route, etc) <-------TCP-------> Host B

Comment: Are you sure those are the only requirements? Or are you going to sneak in fault tolerance, redundancy, message recovery, monitoring, retry, etc on us later?

Comment: @JoeHolloway Good point. No, I am just interested in latency here. I understand these are also important and that I cannot sneak in message recovery because I will not want to do that myself if I am using UDP.

Comment: Are there any routers in the link?

Comment: @MartinJames Let's assume a very descent routers/switch that can deliver the message from A to B efficiently at 10 gigabits.

Answer (score 3):

if you do not require a broker in between, 0MQ gave us the best performance (you will need to test the numbers on your platform/use case).  If using a broker in between, both ActiveMQ & RabbitMQ performed in the same range.  Using Redis as a messaging server did not hold up for us.
If not using a messaging server, options such as Netty, J-groups etc might be useful (not sure about your programming language).

You could look into reliable UDP as well if going with straight socket connectivity.

hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The lower bound would be at least 2 TCP connections and the routing time inside the messaging queue server (meaning the delays associated with these)

Host A <-------TCP-------> Messaging queue (process, route, etc) <-------TCP-------> Host B

Off course, if you build in redundancy, fault tolerance etc, then you are going to be certainly way above this lower bound.

Comment: Awesome, see my edit. I am looking for a messaging queue and its latency number.

Comment: Ok..so the question is "messaging queue and the latency number". First off, IMO the answer depends on the transmission size. Assuming very small payloads that fit in much less than an MTU, the ethernet latency is in the order of dozens of microseconds (for short distances). Add the processing time - network card processing, device driver, OS overhead etc - depends on your hardware and things like whether there is any virtualization etc that can slow things down.

Comment: All messaging queues will be running on the SAME environment under the SAME conditions. That said I would like to know which one is the fastest with some latency numbers, that's it.

Comment: Humn havent seen comparison benchmarks in MQ. Did you Google for this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are talking about an UDP-based MQ because you mentioned MTU. Well, for UDP-based MQs this time is usually measured as the time required to publish a message and see it back in the message bus. So it is a round-trip time, not a one-way time as you described. This can usually be done in less than 6 microseconds, depending of course on your choice of LAN.